# Will I have any problem entering the U.S. with a band aid on my finger?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, biometric-passports

I am boarding a plane to the U.S. in the next few hours and I had to put 2 bandaids on my fingers because of an accident. Would this cause any kind of problem with the immigration official during the biometrical scan?

Answer (score 1):

I accompanied my grandmother on a trip abroad a couple of months ago, where she took a nasty fall. She had severe lacerations on each of the fingers on her left hand. If I remember correctly, the hospital gave her twenty stitches. The immigration officers didn't give her a hard time at all. However, the fact that she was both elderly and had this rather severe injury probably contributed to the officers allowing her to keep her bandages on.

So, I'm not sure what your experience would be like if you have a papercut or another minor injury. But either way, accidents happen. I would like to think that immigration officers understand that, so I don't think you'll be given too much trouble. But if they do ask you to remove your bandages, it would probably be best to be compliant.

Answer (score -3):

Not if the bandages are not covering your fingertips.  If they are, you may be asked to take them off.

Comment: yes, they are covering them. Taking them off I don't think will help much as there is a cut there. Besides it will hurt...

Comment: Sorry, man.  I don't think they are going to just take your word for it.

Comment: Don't think CBP will care if it "hurts", they will want to scan your fingerprint with or without a cut (unless of course you sliced your fingerprint off ;-)

Comment: I just want to know the actual procedure. I don't really think they need to take them out when they can scan my other 8 fingers and my face. If anyone has any facts please share.

Comment: [The procedure is](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/usvisit.html) "Using a ink-less biometric device, your 10 digital fingerprints will be taken. As shown in the above images, you will be fingerprinted with your right four fingers, then right thumb, then left four fingers, then left thumb and a digital photograph with a digital camera will be taken."  If you think claiming to have boo-boo on your finger is going to dissuade a heavily armed government bureaucrat, you have an enviable lack of experience with such bureaucrats.

Comment: @Malvolio Thanks. I am aware about that procedure... I was talking about the procedure in place to handle injuries. :)

Comment: Band aides tend to be used primarily for cleanliness and are not mandatory.  Wound closures such as steri-strips which are used in lieu of stitches are mandatory.  You would likely be asked to remove the former, but allowed to leave the later in place.  However the guidelines that CBP agents use to make determinations are never made public, so no one here can answer with certainty.

Comment: Do they disinfect the device between uses?